# How to bring back an Android application to foreground when GPS location is changed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gps

I am building a Android application which gives Travel Maps.User can navigate away from my application. Ex - Pressing Home button. I want do is, bring back the application on location change.I want to show some notifications on special GPS coordinates. I am using [onLocationChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) method to do my tasks. But I cant find out a way to bring the app to foreground. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I have not done this. But at least you can try.
Inside onLocationChanged() callback put

```
Intent startActivity = new Intent(this,your_class.class ); 
startActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); 
PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, startActivity, 0);
```

Then start that Intent.

Comment: But here one problem arises, that is a new activity will start. Not the existing one.

Comment: Nope. see the diffrent between FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT & other FLAGS. This will bring an existing instance of the called activity type present in the current stack to the foreground (if there is such an instance) instead of creating a new instance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can have your application come to the foreground like that but you can probably show a notification in the notification bar instead. When the user selects that notification you can show your application again.